# Why difference between two pointers is not equals to size of type?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, visual-studio-2015, memory-layout

I have the simple program:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int a = 5;
    int b = 6;
    int* p1 = &a;
    int* p2 = &b;
    std::cout << p1 << " " << p2 << " ,sizeof(int)=" << sizeof(int) << std::endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

It produces the following output:

```
00DBF9B8 00DBF9AC ,sizeof(int)=4
```

but, `00DBF9B8 - 00DBF9AC == С`. I cannot understand this result.

If I modify the program like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    static int a = 5;
    static int b = 6;
    int* p1 = &a;
    int* p2 = &b;
    std::cout << p1 << " " << p2 << " ,sizeof(int)=" << sizeof(int) << std::endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I got correct result:

```
00394000 00394004 ,sizeof(int)=4
```

Comment: There's no requirement for compilers to put local variables one after another

Comment: You cannot subtract pointers that don't point to elements of the same array, or to the first byte behind the array.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I can create 10 variables. All addresses differ by "C".

Comment: @Max ... OK, so?

Comment: Debug or release build?

Comment: @BaummitAugen To be clear, are you saying it's undefined behavior if it is done?

Comment: @RetiredNinja I have debug build

Comment: @melpomene I can conclude that a pattern exists. But I do not know the reason.

Comment: Did you also try a release build? Perhaps your compiler adds additional space around variables in a debug build to catch writing outside of bounds. Even if that's not the reason it doesn't matter, you can't count on memory layout of individual variables.

Comment: @BaummitAugen: nobody is doing anything like that in this code. OP is printing addresses and calculating differences by hand.

Comment: @JamesAdkison Yes.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Good point, thanks.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I try to test my code in Realese mode. This mod has the correct behavior.

Comment: You keep saying "correct behavior", but you haven't shown any incorrect behavior, just incorrect assumptions.

Comment: @RetiredNinja sorry, it is my bad. Thanks for clearing

Comment: Although the underlying assumption that stack allocations are necessarily consecutive is wrong, I don't see why the compiler here is behaving like that. It would be interesting to see an assembly dump of the debug build, I'd be curious to see what's going on there - e.g. if it's filling the 8 bytes in between with stack canary values or something else.

Comment: In your project properties turn C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Basic Runtime Checks to default rather than /RTC1 and check again.  That disables runtime stack frame checking.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I had Default Bisic Runtime Checks, when executed this code

Comment: Make sure you're looking at the debug settings.  I was able to replicate your issue with stack frame checking on, and eliminate it with stack frame checking off.

Comment: if you put these pointer into the a structure and use structure packing they store in memory in consequence order.  https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c/4590/structure-packing#t=201707050543584607619     https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c/10657/structure-padding/31992/simple-example#t=201707050543562396309

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no guarantee that local variables (or even static variables) are put on consecutive memory addresses. And actually it would be undefined behaviour if you substracted two pointer values that do not point into the same array.

But you could use pointer arithmetics as follows:

```
int main()
{
    int a;
    int* p1 = &a;
    int* p2 = p1+1;
    std::cout << p1 << " " << p2 << " ,sizeof(int)=" << sizeof(int) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Note that a single integral value may be considered as an array of size 1, and that `p1+1` therefore points to "one after the last element of an array", such that the operation `p2 = p1+1` is actually valid (dereferencing `p2` then would not be valid, of course).